# Using overlayVisible property in primeNg dropdown

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

PrimeNG multiselect widget has overlayVisible property which makes the multiselect panel visible when widget is loaded.
but PrimeNG dropdown doesn't have such property to enable the panel open by default.

Any idea how it can be done?? Tried using few options like panelStyleClass and setting the panel style on dropdown's focus event but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You really can use the overlayVisible flag. just assign its value in component to be true or false based on the number of multiselect  item.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars1" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" 
[overlayVisible] = "isLoaded">
</p-multiSelect>
```

see demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-mulstiselect?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi Maria, For <p-multiSelect> overlayVisible flag works, but the issue here is <p-dropdown> which is a primeng single select dropdown widget doesn't have overlayVisible property.

Comment: any suggestions? anyone?

Comment: @patchy It will be really helpful if you put together a sample project. I don't think I understand the problem.

Comment: If clicking on drop down the list item is not visible add appendTo="body"

Comment: <p-dropdown [options]="cities2" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity2" optionLabel="name" [overlayVisible] = "isLoaded"></p-dropdown>  here overlayVisible property is not available on p-dropdown, it works only for p-multiselect widget. Trying to get it working for p-dropdown as well